# Proof that a curve is a line given a restriction on it's tangent lines

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, differential-geometry

I'm having a hard time doing this problem and I'd like some insights:

Given a regular curve $\gamma: \rm I\!R \to \rm I\!R^n$, show that if all it's tangent lines pass through a same point $P$, then $\gamma$ is a line or a line segment.

I tried a proof by contradiction, supposing that it not being a line there exists a point where the curvature $\neq 0$ and proceeding to find a contradiction, but it seems to bring me no where as I can prove that the tangents only intersect at $P$ but nothing else.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a proof by contradiction is not necessary.

Since $\gamma$ is regular, we can reparametrise it to a unit speed curve. By assumption, for every $t\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists a $\lambda(t)\in\mathbb{R}$ ($\lambda$ depends on $t$) such that
$$ \gamma(t) +\lambda(t)\gamma'(t) = P.  \label{equa} \tag{*}$$
Deriving this  gives
$$ (1+\lambda'(t)) \gamma'(t) + \lambda(t) \gamma''(t) = 0.$$
Since $\gamma$ has unit speed, it follows that $\gamma''(t)\cdot \gamma'(t)=0$, so $\gamma''(t)$ is a normal vector.

If $\gamma''(t_0)\neq 0$ at some point, then by continuity it is non-zero in some interval $I$ containing $t_0$. Then $\lambda(t)=0$ and thus $\gamma(t)=P$ for $t\in I$,  which would contradict the fact that $\gamma$ is regular. Hence $\gamma''(t)=0$ must hold for all $t$. Integrating this twice gives that $\gamma$ is a line or line segment.

**Edit:** The proof above uses that $\gamma\in C^2$. User Laz suggested in the comments that this statement should also hold if $\gamma \in C^1$. Here is an argument for the case $\gamma \in C^1$.

Write $\gamma(t)=\bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr)$ and $P=(a,b)$. Then \eqref{equa} becomes 
$$
\begin{align*}
 x(t)+\lambda(t) x'(t)= a, \qquad  y(t)+\lambda(t) y'(t)= b.
\end{align*}
$$

If $\lambda(t_0)\neq 0$ in a point $t_0$, then $\lambda(t)\neq 0$ on a open interval containing $t_0$. On this interval we can integrate to obtain
$$ 
  \begin{align*}
 x(t)&= K_1 \exp\left(\int \frac{1}{\lambda(t)}\,dt\right) + a, \\
 y(t)&= K_2 \exp\left(\int \frac{1}{\lambda(t)}\,dt\right) + b, \\
\end{align*}
$$
This is a parametrisation of a line. This local argument shows that $\gamma$ piecewise consists of line segments.

If $\lambda(t)=0$ on some (open) interval, we get as before that $\gamma(t)=P$ on the interval and this contradicts the regularity. So $\lambda(t)=0$ only in isolated points. Now, note that the curve $\gamma(\mathbb{R})$ is connected ($\gamma$ is continuous and $\mathbb{R}$ is connected).  Moreover, $\gamma'(t)$ is continuous so the slopes of all the line segments have to be the same. Hence $\gamma$ is a line.

Comment: Your argument is correct to some extent. The thing is that it can only happen one of two things for every $t$: $\gamma^{''}(t)=0$ or not, but pointwise. How do you garantee that both cases separate uniformly along the curve: $\gamma^{''}(t) = 0$ $\forall t$ or $\gamma^{''}(t) \neq 0$ $\forall t$?

Comment: Indeed, I've been a bit sloppy, but it directly follows from continuity. I'll add it.

Comment: Now you got it! The thing is that the acceleration always nonzero was not an option.

Comment: Wow, thank you for that amazing proof, I really love it and I understand it completely. I was missing the piece of the puzzle of introducing the lambda constant and finding the general equation. Thank you very much! One last question. Could we say it MUST have at least one interval $I$ where $\gamma''\neq 0$ since it is not a straight line?

Comment: Nevermind, I wrote too fast, it's exactly the definition of curvature lol

Comment: @Laz I was aware of this fact before writing it down. The thing is, after doing many of these proofs, one often forgets to include the standard arguments. But this is not an excuse :) Thank you for the constructive comment.

Comment: @Tommy-Xavier Robillard I'm glad you understand the proof. I am sorry I was sloppy before.

Comment: Your are welcome, @Ernie060. In your proof (which is probably the one I would have done, since one always assume a lot of good properties from objects) you used that $\gamma$ is $C^2$. Now I propose a new question, and this is also for the OP, would it still be true if we didn't require the acceleration to be continuous? Furthermore, what if not even the speed was required to be continuous, just nonzero?

Comment: I don't have the time right now to try and solve it, but (and this is just geometric intuition) I suspect it's still true if the speed is continuous, but we can't drop this condition ...

Comment: @Laz That is an interesting suggestion. I added an argument for the case $\gamma \in C^1$. Comments are welcome.

Comment: Great answer! Pitty I can only upvote once.